# How can i set each color of a pie Chart in iOS Charts separately with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

i am working on an iOS App to create a pie Chart with Swift in Xcode.
I added the iOS Charts Framework.

How can i set  each color of a pie chart separately with iOSCharts and  Swift??

I did not found something in the MPAndroid Charts Wiki Page. Only how to set the color of a dataset as a whole. But i want to set each color of a value of the Array separately on my own, if possible.

By the Way, i followed the Steps in this Tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

So, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some trial and error, now i found a "workaround" to set a color separately.

```
self.pieChartView.data?.getDataSetByIndex(0).colors[3] = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

This will set the third value in the piechart to orange.
Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: chartView.data?.getDataSetByIndex(0)?.colors[0] = UIColor(hex: "#04BA9C"), It is a get only property.

Comment: It should be like chartView.data?.getDataSetByIndex(0)?.setColor(UIColor(hex: "#04BA9C"))

Comment: As of Oct 30, 2020 should be chartView.data?[0].setColor(UIColor(hex: "#04BA9C"))

Answer (score 5):

Try This:

```
var  colors: [UIColor] = []
     colors.append(UIColor.green)
     colors.append(UIColor.blue)
     colors.append(UIColor.black)

    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
```

Answer (score 2):

In the tutorial you linked, you can see how they set the colours for the pie chart like so:

```
for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
    let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

    let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
    colors.append(color)
}
pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
```